# Custom user types getting html sanitized in posts

Tags: user-roles

For default user types (admin, editor, etc.) style tags are not stripped from posts when saved. For custom user types, style tags are being stripped.

I've applied filters in my funcitons.php file to prevent stripping, but it's ignored when logged in as a custom user type. I've also directly edited TinyMCE in the wp-includes folder, and even that is ignored.

Here is how the user type is registered in my plugin;

```
function add_roles_on_plugin_activation_tester() {
add_role( 'tester', ' Tester', array(
    'delete_others_pages' => true,
    'delete_others_posts' => true,
    'delete_pages' => true,
    'delete_posts' => true,
    'delete_private_pages' => true,
    'delete_private_posts' => true,
    'delete_published_pages' => true,
    'delete_published_posts' => true,
    'edit_others_pages' => true,
    'edit_others_posts' => true,
    'edit_pages' => true,
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'edit_private_pages' => true,
    'edit_private_posts' => true,
    'edit_published_pages' => true,
    'edit_published_posts' => true,
    'manage_categories' => true,
    'manage_links' => true,
    'moderate_comments' => false,
    'publish_pages' => true,
    'publish_posts' => true,
    'read' => true,
    'read_private_pages' => true,
    'read_private_posts' => true,
    'unfiltered_html ' => true,
    'upload_files' => true,
    'level_1' => true
) );
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 
'add_roles_on_plugin_activation_tester' );
```

This occurs on standard post types, and custom post types using ACF ver. 5.7.10 custom fields.

WordPress ver. 4.9.9

Comment: `unfiltered_html` should be giving you that capability.  try removing `level_1` as that converts to `contributor` which does no have the unfiltered html cap.  I'm making wild guesses here but it's possible that it's overriding your settings.

Comment: You're right, I was missing unfiltered_html, I tried removing level_1 before but adding unfiltered solved it, if you want, add this as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `'unfiltered_html' => true,` in your capabilities.  you have an extra space in yours.